# Getting data with backbone .fetch from a static .json file

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Not sure why this isn't working, the app loads fine.  I just get the error each time the load function is called without even requesting the json file.

Ive used this same code to load data from a java controller and it works fine, not sure how the static json file is different.

The View:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'validate',
  'collections/getBusiness',
  'text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, validate, getBusiness, homeTemplate){

 var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $("#page"),

   events: {
     'click #data': 'data'
    },

    data: function(e) {
        getBusiness.fetch({
            success: function(r) {

            },
            error: function(r) {
                alert('error!');
            }
        });
    },

render: function(){

  this.$el.html(homeTemplate);

}

  });

  return HomeView;

});
```

The Model:

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

var getModel = Backbone.Model.extend({


  });

  return getModel;

});
```

The Collection:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/getModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, getModel){
  var getBusiness = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: getModel,

    url: '../../json/data.json',

sync: function(method, model, options) {

    options.timeout = 100000;
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            options.cache = false;
            options.dataType = "json";
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
},

parse: function(response) {
            return this.result;
},

  });

  return new getBusiness;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you running your application from a server, because you will get a cross-domain scripting error if running the application from your directory. Anyway also curious as to why you are overriding the sync method. Describe the error in more detail and maybe give us an indication of the error you receive in the console.

Comment: It's returning the error alert

Comment: I am just running locally as a test app not on a server, the error it's returning is:    error: function(r) {
                alert('error!');
            }

Comment: The reason for the sync override, is bc this is a test app for interviewee's and the app they will be working on uses the sync override for posting/deleting so it's a way for them to be familiar with it prior to starting.